# How to show English number as bangla unicode format in html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have stored number font in english format in my database. How to show that number in bangla unicode font format while fetching data into my html page, using javascript??

Comment: import a font then set the font family in css?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function to convert English number to Bangla in Javascript.

```
let banglaNumber = {
  0: "০",
  1: "১",
  2: "২",
  3: "৩",
  4: "৪",
  5: "৫",
  6: "৬",
  7: "৭",
  8: "৮",
  9: "৯",
};
const engToBdNum = (str) => {
  for (var x in banglaNumber) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(x, "g"), banglaNumber[x]);
  }
  return str;
};

console.log(engToBdNum('4234234000324234'))
// output ৪২৩৪২৩৪০০০৩২৪২৩৪
```

jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/shuhad/tx5unfdy

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using language specific translation files and using standard javascript  methods to translate data into given format as per the local. So you can set the local for bangla (bn_IN) language and apply the translations from translation files. You can use libraries like [formatjs](https://formatjs.io/) or alike as per your application frameworks.  Even though it is not recommended but if you want to do it yourself without any libraries just for few strings in bangla only than simply put the translations in object and replace it while display in html. e.g.

//english to bangla

```
let translations = {
   'Hi How Are You ?' : 'হাই, আপনি কেমন আছেন ?',
   'Test': 'পরীক্ষা'
}
```

use this to replace english contents with bangla contents